# Regex issue with URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to create a particular regex that might contain these sentences below:

The Test:

```
/ff/page
/test/page/
/pa/my-page
/cc/my-page/aboutus
/pc/my-page/about-us
```

Result:

```
/ff/page
/test/page
/cc/my-page
/pb/my-page
/pc/my-page
```

This regex must be in a single line as this will be inserted in a text box in our CMS. The CMS is in asp.net c#

Till now I have creating something similar to this:

```
\/cc\/([0-9,a-z,A-Z,-])
```

but of course it only targets those that has `cc` in it.

I made a test for this particular regex which can be found: [Regexr](http://regexr.com?368b3)
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+
```

[Updated regexr](http://regexr.com?368bc)

`[^/]+` matches all characters except forward slashes